# How to track things that SHOULD happen, but might not have

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring

I am running into a couple of issues with some applications we've deployed and maintain. I have the feeling we have approached this with some anti-patterns up to now, but I would like to see how to make this more flexible and stable.

In one situation, we have a server at a client which pushes data to us to parse every night (yes, Windows Task Scheduler). This is highly unstable however, so once every month this doesn't happen because of reasons out of our control. This heavily impacts our business since we run with stale data in that situation.

In another scenario we have a lot of background job processes that should be running. We already keep them up using bluepill ( http://www.github.com/arya/bluepill ) but obviously restarts happen, both automatically and manually, and people forget things or systems mess up.

What I would like to track is events that should occur or should be available. Like the existence of a process, the execution of a program, or the creation/age of a file, and track it when they *don't* happen or exist.

We develop most things in Ruby on Rails, use NewRelic, Bluepill and Munin, and run on Ubuntu. I've been toying around with counting `ps aux | grep processname | wc -l` in Munin scripts, or capturing the age of a file and raising alerts over 24-26 hours, stuff like that.

Is there better tooling to track things that should happen, and raise alerts if they don't?

P.S. I know some things are suboptimal, like manually having to define bluepill for applications and then forgetting to do so. The same goes for the push based approach of the first application, a dedicated daemon that manages that on the client side that we control and can track its connection to us might be a much better solution.

Comment: This is... just way too broad to be a good question.  But in the general case:  (pseudocode) `if [thing you're looking for] exists, break; else, [trigger alert];.`

Comment: yes, I know I can use cronjobs and such. But since monitoring tools exist we can streamline those things. Just wondering if some tools have a more native approach to tracking absence of some thing or event, since most tend to focus on presence.

Comment: This got closed as it appears to be searching for an off-the-shelf solution to your monitoring problem, which triggers our [shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/qa) reflexes. However, your question *is* answerable without resorting to product recommendations. So I'm reopening it.

Comment: Thanks! I am indeed looking for a sensible method of dealing with this rather than just a list of products.

Answer (score 4):

Most quality monitoring frameworks that work well in the Linux space have the ability to have custom-written probes. These can often be used over SSH, which allows you to essentially write bash scripts that get run every time the monitoring system probes your assets. From the sounds of it, you'll need two custom probes:

1. If the modification time-stamp of a file is older than now-X, alert.
2. If $processName doesn't show up in the running processes list, alert.

Alternately, you can tie these scripts to your snmpd process, so when a specific OID is accessed they're run and return their value. Darned near everything can do SNMP.

In my experience, pre-built probes rarely handle the file-exists or file-too-old events, but some do include the ability to test that certain long-running executables are running.

Answer (score 0):

We use monit or mmonit (http://mmonit.com/monit/) for these kind of things. You can define it to look at files, timestamps, if something exist or even to run your script and check for output.